# Virtualbox 5.2 has no Global menu on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, virtualbox

After upgrading from Virtualbox 5.1.30 to Virtualbox 5.2 the File, Machine...Device menu no longer appears in the top panel.  Is global menu no longer supported for Virtualbox 5.2?

Clarification: a nice feature in Ubuntu 16.04 is that the menu items (File Machine View Input Devices Help) would appear in Ubuntu's top panel next to the (close/minimize/maximize) buttons.  I can then maximize the Virtualbox window and turn off Virtualbox's top and bottom menu bars for a nearly seamless full screen experience.  The problem is that with Virtualbox 5.2 the menu no longer appears in Ubuntu's top panel. I can still access the menu using the right control + home keys, but this should not be necessary.  Has this behavior been purposely changed or do I have a corrupted installation?

---

Update :  I just wanted to report that the global menu is now working after updating to Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity desktop and Virtualbox 6.02.
Great News!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this issue is related to the "Qt Theme issue" (https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17218), and is caused by the usage of an internal Qt 5.6.1 library, needed by virtualBox 5.2.

Ubuntu 16.04 has Qt 5.5.1, that comes with custom theme, integrated with Gtk / Unity environment, but VirtualBox 5.2 need Qt 5.6.2, and so uses an integrated standard version of the library.

I think that the integrated Qt library not only does not have the custom theme, but also does not work with "global menu".

So the only solution I found is to enable the standard menu in the VM settings, under section "User interface".

Comment: PS: now I've reverted to old version 5.1.30, waiting for upgrading Ubuntu to 18.04 LTS, when will be available, hoping that it will include Qt 5.6.1